# Unable to upgrade DotNet Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, .net

I have Visual Studio 2019 with .Net-2.2 installed on my windows-10 system. When I tried to run a project with .NET Core 3.1, it fails. It was complaining that I need to upgrade to 3.1. Then I downloaded NET Core 3.1 SDK and installed it.

When I run the applications, it still fails. So I check the available framework in the application, I only saw .NET Core-2.2 and didn't see 3.1. What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of application you're developing? Also, can you please clarify "it fails"? Thanks!

Comment: Check the [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).  You got the "build apps" download, you also need the "run apps" download.

Comment: @CoolBots. AspNet Core c#

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 must be at least version 16.7 for it to recognize .NET Core 3.1. If you don't have that version or higher, it won't show up in the list of available target frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Assuming your project is an ASP.NET Core project

There are a lot of breaking changes in ASP.NET Core 3.1. You will need to update your code / project accordingly. The following guide will help you with migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

### For general .NET Core scenario

Here is the list of all the breaking changes when migrating from 2.2 to 3.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1

Comment: Why do you think this is ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. It seems I may have made a wrong assumption here. However, the suggestion to migrate is still applicable due to all the known breaking changes. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Artak - .NetCore-3.1 is still not appearing in the Target Framework. I still have 2.2 there

Comment: Oh, I see. So you're going into project properties in VS, and trying to change the target framework from there? You can always modify the project file manually and use `netcoreapp3.1` as your target framework. However, the fact that VS doesn't show it it means it either doesn't see .NET 3.1 SDK installed or VS version is old. Can you try to upgrade VS to the latest version and then install .NET Core 3.1 SDK ?